# ImportError: dynamic module does not define module export function (PyInit__constant_time)

Tags: python, scrapy, python-3.6

I want to execute a Python script using Scrapy:

```
from scrapy import cmdline
cmdline.execute("scrapy crawl woodenrobot".split())
```

But I got this error:

> ImportError: dynamic module does not define module export function (PyInit__constant_time)

Is this a Python version error? My python version is 3.6